# computer on PCIe card

Tags: assembly, embedded, hardware, microcontroller, fpga

Does anyone know a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-on-module) which is put on a PCIe card, which has some flash memory, some RAM, JTAG support (or some kind of debugging support), some input ports like USB, perhaps support some output like via VGA or LVDS, just like this board: http://www.knjn.com/FPGA-PCIe.html but not for FPGA development, but for microprocessors, preferably x86.

Something similar [has been done](http://hardware.slashdot.org/hardware/08/10/02/2244229.shtml) in the past, but the link is dead, and it should have enough documentation and be hacker-friendly (and cheap, not more than 100-150 USD).

I will be writing the driver for the host system (linux), for inter-system communication, but the PCIe board itself should be pretty stand-alone (beside the operating system for the "guest OS" on the PCIe card which I will also have to write).

Thanks

Comment: Guys, it would be nice to also tell me where to ask instead, if you really want to close my question, don't you think? I mean, I am not aware of a more knowledgeable community like this one, but if you know one, feel free to tell me about it. That'd be great.

Comment: Hard to say, @Flavius. This really isn't on-topic for any Stack Exchange site I know of.  The [Electronics and Robotics beta](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), maybe.

Comment: Do you actually require a PCIe card, or just "small" ?  Do you really need an x86 or would the more common ARM devices work?  Ram and flash requirements? What kinds of tasks does the board need to do - I/O? Realtime?  Communication with the host or other networks?   Does it need a serious embedded O/S like linux, a lightweight one, or do you want to run bare metal?

Comment: A PCIe, just like this http://www.advantech.com.tw/products/PCE-5120/mod_B16C5C03-4498-49DD-BEF8-1ECF1890B322.aspx, but for home computers, not for high-end servers, which I could stick directly onto my mainboard. A sodimm slot on it would be great. It would run a linux, yes, but I think I'd have to write the drivers for it, beside any actual job software it would run.

Comment: Much like the SunPCI Sun used to have, but easy to get for home users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this question while looking for something similar myself. A little late to the party, I know :)

Check out the 'PCI/PCI Express Series' under 'Half sized CPU cards' on IEI World's site:

http://www.ieiworld.com/

Answer (score -1):

You're not going to find anything of that sort for anything close to that price range.  The "similar" board you link to (which had a Cell processor) is probably an $8000 board -- at least, that's what the other similar Cell boards I knew of sold for.  And Cell was expensive, sure, but it's not like a Cell processor is $7850 more than an x86 processor.

The closest thing to what you're looking for in that price range are things like evaluation boards that you can buy from chip manufacturers (e.g., [this ARM board, which retails for $70](http://www.luminarymicro.com/products/ekc-lm3s6965_ethernet_evaluation_kit.html)), and those aren't very close.  For reference, that example is about the cheapest board you can get with a 32-bit processor and an ethernet port -- and it's that cheap in large part because TI is using it to promote their ARM processor that it contains.  There aren't any chipmakers for x86 other than Intel and AMD, so you won't get that sort of subsidy on the board, to begin with.  And then you're asking for lots more off-chip extras on the board -- USB (ok, probably similar in cost to Ethernet), RAM, video output.  (Not to mention that the TI ARM processor is a system-on-chip that contains flash controller, flash, and lots of other basic things in the chip that you don't get in an x86 chip.)  Oh, and you want a PCIe device-side interface, too.

And all of this, in a package that is definitely not going to sell in high volume.  (The Cell and FPGA boards have a market as fast specialized coprocessor boards; an x86 board is of no use for that because you can just put the extra x86 on the motherboard instead.)  You'd be quite lucky to get something like that under $1000, much less near $100.

With that said, I have seen PCI-bus 486 computers of roughly this ilk (EGA graphics, of course) at [HSC Surplus](http://www.halted.com) in Santa Clara, about three years ago though they don't have any now.  They looked like they had been built when a 486 was a nice processor, and were selling for about $30.  And, on reflection, I'm not sure they were PCI; I think they might have been ISA.  Your best bet would probably be tracking down something like that.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but accepted for the wealth of information provided. Cheers.